# upgrading an O.S. affects which file systems?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, upgrade

I will be upgrading my O.S. from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10.
As its recommended to take back-up before doing that, I'm interested to know which file systems are affected by upgrading so that I need to take back up of those only.

When I installed my O.S. I had created these 4 partitions:

```
/
/boot
/home
swap
```

Then later I had created 3 more partitions sda9, sda10 and sda11 by utilizing the unallocated space. I have taken some back-ups on these 3 newly created partitions.
Now, may I presume that these 3 partitions won't be affected at all by the up gradation?

I have a related post of mine [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104329/back-up-which-patitions-to-back-up-before-upgrading-reinstalling) but couldn't get resolved there.

Comment: You shouldn't re-post your question if it doesn't get answered on the first attempt. Either edit to clarify the original question, offer a bounty on the original question, or edit this question to make it substantially different from the other question.

Comment: As far as i know, the when upgrading an Ubuntu from the built-in updater, the partition which it resides in, will get the software updates. file  systems wise, it doesn't do anything to you fs, it was before an ?ext4? it will remain that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using different partition for each then `/boot` and `/` will definitly be rewritten probably from scratch.
Considering the home it's normally not overwrite, but the existence of some specific paramter in your home can cause malfunction on the new version.

So you can make a backup of the hidden files in your home, and remove them to start ubuntu on clear basis.